# Which is the best way to create a constructor with string parameter?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6

I got the warning

> "Can't resolve all parameters for WeekParserFormatter in week-parser-formatter.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v6.x "

when create a constructor with string parameter:

```
class WeekParserFormatter {
    constructor(
        private dateFormatString: string
     ) {
    }
 }
```

I worked around by following code:

```
class WeekParserFormatter {
     private dateFormatString : string = '';
     setDateFormat(dateFormatString: string){
          this.dateFormatString = dateFormatString;
     }
  }
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: remove one `dateFormatString` variable

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have it as a parameter to constructor, you can directly have it in this variable and use it anywhere inside that class or component

```
Class A {
private dateFormatString : string = '';
  constructor(
  ) {
  }
  setDateFormat(dateFormatString: string){
  this.dateFormatString = dateFormatString;
}
}
```

Comment: Declare dateFormatString as parameter of constructor make it easy to create new class: For example: const instance = new WeekParserFormatter('mediumDate');

Comment: If you want to pass as a parameter to constructor and initialize the class, do like this,
 Class A {
private dateFormat : string = '';
  constructor(private dateFormatString: string
  ) {
       this.dateFormat  = dateFormatString;
  }
  setDateFormat(dateFormatString: string){
  this.dateFormat = dateFormatString;
}
}